# Determine the isometric group $G$ which transfers a square into it self

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, permutations

I am solving the following exercise:

> Determine the isometric group $G$ of the euclidean plane which
>   transfers a square into it self. The restriction of an element $g \in G$ on the  vertices of that square is a permutation of the vertices.
>   Which permutations of the vertices will be maintained?

**My knowledge:** Since we just started our second chapter which covers the topic of isometry on a plane I don't have enough knowledge to conclude if my solution is sufficient enough. I would be very glad if you could comment and if necessary correct my solution.

During our lectures we made a list of isometry types:

orientation-preserving:

- translation
- rotation

orientation-reversing:

- reflection
- glide

in addition to it we said that the set of orientation-preserving isometries is a group. So using this knowledge i came to

**My Solution:** In the beginning i had trouble to understand the sentence because of this 'restriction' thing. After reading the sentence a couple of times I somehow figured out what the exercise wants me to do. So I thought of all isometries that transfer a square into it self. As a result we can neglect the two isometric types *translation* and *glide*. So therefore i worked with *rotations ($rt$)* and *reflections ($rf$)*. There are three rotations (4th would be identity) and four reflections. Let's consider a square with the vertices 1,2,3 and 4. By applying:

$rt_1$ we obtain $ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1  & 2  & 3 & 4\\
 2  & 3  & 4 & 1
\end{array}$

$rt_2$ we obtain $ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1  & 2  & 3 & 4\\
 3  & 4  & 1 & 2
\end{array}$

$rt_3$ we obtain $ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1  & 2  & 3 & 4\\
 4  & 1  & 2 & 3
\end{array}$

a fourth rotation would be the identity so therefore $rt_4 = id$. With the reflections we have the possibility to reflect on a perpendicular *(y-axis)* and horizontal *(x-axis)* line *(considering the middle of the square would be $(0,0)$)* or reflect on the two diagonals. By applying the reflections we get:

$rf_1$ we obtain $ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1  & 2  & 3 & 4\\
 4  & 3  & 2 & 1
\end{array}$

$rf_2$ we obtain $ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1  & 2  & 3 & 4\\
 2  & 1  & 4 & 3
\end{array}$

$rf_3$ we obtain $ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1  & 2  & 3 & 4\\
 3  & 2  & 1 & 4
\end{array}$

$rf_4$ we obtain $ \begin{array}{cccc}
 1  & 2  & 3 & 4\\
 1  & 4  & 3 & 2
\end{array}$

the permutations we can see above are the ones which will be maintained by the group $G = \{ id, rt_1, rt_2, rt_3, rf_1, rf_2, rf_3, rf_4 \}$. As we can see $G = D_4$.

Comment: This looks good to me, except that the group is $D_4$, not $S_4$ (which of course has too many elements).

Comment: thank you! you're absolutely right, we did not cover the dihedral group so far but i just checked it on wikipedia.

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: To get the isometries of a plane figure try to match edges. Fix an edge of your square. You can now place this edge over any other edge, and even make a flip. This should convince you that there are $2 \times 4 =8$ transformations of the square.

Comment: I understand your approach but I think in this way I have not considered what we've covered in our lectures so far but thank you for your input!